# Add all data from file to structure in Elixir

Tags: graph, functional-programming, elixir

I am very new to Elixir and Functional Programming.

I am reading a large text file that describes a graph, and need to store it in a Adjacency Matrix and/or Adjacency List for calculations.

I am having a hard problem trying to figure out how to keep **storing the values in a data structure** , since **data is immutable** in Functional Programming.

The file is such as this:

```
3      //Number of Nodes
1 2    //Non-directional edge
3 4
4 2
```

**Q1**: How can this be done ? **[SOLVED]**

**Q2**: Can this be done with a Stream instead of a full file read ?

Comment: Can you given an example of the output you are seeking, too?

Comment: You do not update variables in FP, you just produce new variables. Both reducers and recursion might help to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one fixed way to parse string into a data structure. For simple cases like this, `String.split` and `String.to_integer` are good enough. You haven't provided the exact output structure you want so I'll show how to decode this into an integer and a list of pair of integers for the edges.

```
input = "3
1 2
3 4
4 2"

# or input = File.read!("file.txt")

[head | tail] = String.split(input, "\n")
count = String.to_integer(head)
edges = for line <- tail do
  [from, to] = String.split(line)
  {String.to_integer(from), String.to_integer(to)}
end

IO.inspect count
IO.inspect edges
```

Output:

```
3
[{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}]
```

Comment: There is a problem with the map you create. It  would only work if each node had only one edge. The code " %{1 => 2, 1 => 4, 1 => 3}  " would generate a map where %{1 => 3}  is the only element

Comment: It works fine if you change it to a list. For me to accept your answer, can you please edit  "into: %{} "  to " into: []"    and    "{String ... integer(to)}" to "[String ... integer(to)]" ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've changed the output to a list of tuples. I think that'd be more idiomatic than a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

You have pretty much two options in functional languages:

1. recursion
2. reduce (specifically, `Enum.reduce`)

Reduce is really quick and easy if you just need to accumulate a value from a list.

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2

It almost sounds like recursion is the way to go with the problem you're trying to solve:

```
File.read!("path/to/file.txt")
|> String.split("\n", trim: true)
|> parse(%{})

def parse([line | rest], matrix) do
  add_line_to_matrix(line, matrix)
  parse(rest, matrix)
end
```

Comment: Guess I wouldn't be able to accomplish this with a Stream of data would I ? 
All the solutions seem to take all the data at once, or accumulate it to recurse over it later.
This isn't a problem, but it got me curious.

Answer (score 1):

Another example with a reducer:

```rb
(1..10)
|> Enum.to_list # or "file.txt" |> File.read! |> String.split("\n")
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn i, acc ->
     Map.put acc, <<i + 96 :: utf8>>, i
end)
#⇒ %{
#    "a" => 1,
#    "b" => 2,
#    ...
#    "j" => 10
#  }
```